# Rails not see compiled files by webpack when webpack-dev-server is runing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, manifest.json

When I run  webpack-dev-server, it compile ONLY manifest.json file with paths to compiled .js and .js.map files.

And when I start rails server, I can watch in google console that it cant find compiled js files:

`GET http://localhost:3001/packs/js/application-f382a9fe03d59bcf5484.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

How to solve this?

Here is my config/webpack/development.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const environment = require('./environment')
environment.config.output.filename = '[name]-[hash].js'
module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Top</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

config/webpacker.yml

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: true
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, resolved by updating config/webpack/development.js

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')
const config = environment.toWebpackConfig();
config.output.filename = "[name].js"

module.exports = config;
```